# Styling the Grid-View in visual studio express 2010

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

I used the ultimate version and when i wanted to style grid view to different colors lets say,i just moved over the mouse over the Grid-View code,and there was an option to change the look of the Grid-View,in express version i don't have this option.can i enable it? or its just not there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example ,

```
<asp:gridview runat="server" cellpadding="5" cssclass="GridView" gridlines="None">
<headerstyle cssclass="GridViewHeader" forecolor="#ffffff" verticalalign="Bottom" />
<rowstyle cssclass="GridViewRow" verticalalign="Top" />
<alternatingrowstyle cssclass="GridViewAlternatingRow" verticalalign="Top" />
<editrowstyle cssclass="GridViewEditRow" verticalalign="Top" />
<selectedrowstyle cssclass="GridViewSelectedRow" verticalalign="Top" />
<footerstyle cssclass="GridViewFooter" />
<pagerstyle cssclass="GridViewPager" />
</asp:gridview>
```

You can reference in
[GridView-makeover-using-CSS](http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx)
[ASP.net Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1001626.aspx/1)
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) !
Good Luck  :)

Comment: yes i see,but my question is,is there a shortcut to create costume design like in the ultimate version?

Comment: Like i said before,i just moved with the mouse cursor over the gridview word in the aspx page,and it gave me like a little button to press and than i had allot of options to change the style of the gridview.

Comment: OK i managed to make it work!,i change the view to " Design view" and i did it from there!